# How to install a stand-alone program

Tags: apt, software-installation, gcc, c

If I create the following program in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

And then compile it like so:

`gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld`

Is there any easy way to install `helloworld` on to my computer?

Comment: ehm it is already on your computer ;-) Next step: make it executable (chmod 664 helloworld) and then you can execute it with ./helloworld.

Comment: But is there any way to install it so I can type helloworld into the terminal from any directory @Rinzwind

Comment: That is not "installing" but copying it into a directory that is included in your PATH  Something like `sudo cp helloworld /usr/local/bin/`. After you made it executable ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I can understand from reading [this guide on deb packaging](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=910717) , that's kind of what really happens under the hood - the source files are packaged into deb file, once they arrive at a pc , the source is just compiled and executables are shoved into appropriate dirs. Correct ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo install helloworld /usr/local/bin` installs it to `/usr/local/bin` (read `man install`).
Btw, your helloworld.c should really be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [About the int main (void)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12225214/3701431) , not really necessary.

Comment: It's just good practice.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any easy way to install helloworld on to my computer?

The next actions you need to do:

1. make the file executable with `chmod 775 helloworld` from the directory where the file is.
2. copy it over to a directory in your PATH. I would suggest `sudo cp helloworld /usr/local/bin/` (local since it is your local system and bin since it is a binairy).

And then you can do

```
helloworld
```

from any location on the system to have it print "Hello world".

Comment: Why 664? It'll make it unexcutable, 755 should be used. And gcc already makes it executable by default.

Answer (score 3):

Without `root` permission the best thing for you to do is create a `bin` directory within your home directory and then add it to your `PATH` environment variable. So after creating a directory called `bin` in /home/$USER open `~/.bashrc` in your favourite editor, for example `gedit ~/.bashrc`. You then need to add:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

What this is doing is appending `~/bin` to the $PATH variable. Which is a list of directories to search for executables.

If you've got a terminal currently open, you need to reload the configuration what you can do by using the `source` command: `source ~/.bashrc`.

Finally you just need to copy the executable into that directory then you'll be able to run it as you would a normal command.

As pointed out by @Serg in the comments the `~/bin` directory is included in the `PATH` set in `~/.profile`. So alternatively you can simply edit `~/.profile` and remove the comment from the `PATH` variable. Simply find the line:

```
# PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Then change it to the following and reload the terminal:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: 1 thing: this will make it possible to execute if from only this user you did this for. If you need it for more than 1 user use a global directory (like `/usr/local/bin` And yes that requires "sudo" permissions).

Comment: Yes, if you require it to be executable for multiple users then @Rinzwind answer is the way to do it. It has the benefit of not needing to modify the `PATH`

Comment: A side note: `.profile` actually contains the following line 
`#    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` , so the user alternatively could just uncomment that in their `.profile` file